# python pandas -- improve the speed of multiple assignments

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to impute a pandas dataframe of the shape (30000000, 22). However, the way I am doing it right now by using a `for` loop to collect all the indices, columns and new values to assign and then using `.loc` method to assign everything all at once is very slow. While the `for` loop is not unreasonably slow, the assignment using `.loc` at the end is taking forever, as there are about 2100000 values to assign. I was wondering if there is another way that can get the work done with a reasonable amount of time. Thank you so much:)

```
def impute_original_data(data):
    data_copy = data.copy()
    missing_indices = []
    missing_columns = []
    replacements = []
    for i in range(data_copy.shape[0]):
        if i % 100000 == 0:
            print(i)
        pd_index = data_copy.iloc[i].name
        current_row = data_copy.iloc[i]
        if current_row['a'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('a')
            replacements.append(current_row['z'])
        if current_row['b'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('b')
            replacements.append(current_row['z'])
        if current_row['c'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('c')
            replacements.append(current_row['z'])
        if current_row['d'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('d')
            replacements.append(1)
        if current_row['e'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('e')
            replacements.append(current_row['z'])
        if current_row['f'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('f')
            replacements.append(0.000000001)
        if current_row['g'] == 0:
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('g')
            replacements.append(1)
        elif pd.isnull(current_row['h']):
            missing_indices.append(pd_index)
            missing_columns.append('h')
            replacements.append(1)
    data_copy.loc[missing_indices, missing_columns] = replacements
    return data_copy
```

Comment: This is a totally inefficient way to iterate over a pandas dataframe. `current_row = data_copy.iloc[i]` is totally slow. Use `itertuples`, and to assign to a single value, use `df.at[idx, col] = <whatever>`. Better yet, you should probabyl be using vectorized operations if possible

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Thank you so much for your wonderful answer. It is extremely fast now.

Comment: I suspect the aggergate `data_copy.loc[missing_indices, missing_columns] = replacements` would be a lot faster if it involved `numpy.ndarray` objects instead of lists. However, incrememntally building up those arrays would be slow

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would you mind teaching me how to use vectorized operations for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This way would be more vectorised:

```
missing_indices = data[(data == 0).any(axis=1) == True].index.values

missing_columns = data.columns[(data == 0).any()].values
```

What this is doing is: If there is a row with one or more 0's, add that row's index to the missing_indices list. And if there is a column with one or more 0's, add that column's name to the missing_columns list.

I didn't quite understand what you are doing with the replacements. Most of them you are setting to be the value of column 'z', and then you have a 0.000000001 and a 1. Probably you just filled that randomly for posting, so you could get a more general solution. Since I couldn't infer what your replacements mean precisely, I'll wait for you to provide a lil' bit more information.

Hope that I could use you some help, though =)